# How to use a Firebase app without google_services.json?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following issue. I have created a project using Firebase as my backend and someone is asking me for this project. I've sent him the project but without the `google_services.json` file. From know reasons, Android Studio is complaining that is unable to run the project because:

```
google_services.json file is missing
```

Is it save to send the `google_services.json` as well? If I'll send the file, will he be able to see all my databases? Or how can my friend use the app that I've sent to him?

Comment: I don't think it's a bad thing to send your google_services.json.. since anybody could decompile your apk anytime. The main security you should do is the rules in firebase

Comment: You think or are you sure? There is no authentication in that app. There are only some reads.

Comment: ok then just fix your firebase rules... but hey.. how do you manage your rules if there is no Auth ? read true, write false ?

Comment: I don't. That's why I said that there is no auth, it is just a simple app that reads some data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it save to send the `google_services.json` as well?

The `google_services.json` contains the configuration data that your app needs to find its Firebase project on the servers. Is does not automatically allow access to the project though.

> If I'll send the [`google_services.json`] file, will he be able to see all my databases?

That depends on the security rules of your databases. If you've set them to be publicly readable, then your friend will be able to read/write to them. But so will everyone else who happens to discover the URL/ID of your project.

To prevent that you'll want to set specific access rules for your databases. To get started on these, I highly recommend reading the documentation on security rules for [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) and [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview). There's also a great video from the Firebase Summit last month: [Five tips to secure your app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvLkkLjHdkw).

Comment: Yes, this what I need to do, I'll start with the documentation on security rules. Thank you for the helpful answer and useful resources.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't use any authentication, setup your rules as follow:

```
{
"rules": 
 {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
 }
}
```

There is no danger to give your google_services.json since it's attach to this database only. If you really want security, add the authentication and setup your rules.

Take note, now you won't be able to write data to your database except from the server side (firebase-admin in cloud functions). So you may create some cloud functions that will write the data you send via an http request for example.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.